# How do I display a list of posts under all hierarchical children of the current taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, hierarchical

Assume the following custom taxonomy structure:

- USA

  - California

    - Los Angeles
    - San Francisco
    - Oakland
  - New York

    - New York
    - Buffalo
    - Rochester

*Note: It's just sample data, so don't bother to correct it!*

Now, assume the following custom post type data:

- Some posts will be country-wide, so they will only be assigned to the **USA** category.
- Some posts will only be valid in certain states, so they will get assigned only those categories, eg. **California** or **New York**.
- Some posts will only be valid in certain cities, so they will get assigned only to those categories, eg. **Los Angeles** or **Rochester**.

I want to configure WordPress such that:

1. If I browse to a top-level category (eg. **USA**), it should show a list of posts that belong to **USA** as well as every descendant, eg. **California**, **Los Angeles**, **New York**, **Rochester**, etc., i.e. the whole country.
2. If I browse to a mid-level category (eg. **California**), it should show the obvious list of posts belonging to that category as well as all descendants, i.e. **California**, **Los Angeles**, **San Fransisco**, **Oakland**, etc., but it should also show me all posts that are tagged with the top level, i.e. **USA**.
3. If I browse to the last level category page, (eg. **Buffalo**), it should show me posts in **Buffalo**, it's parent, **New York** and it's grandparent, **USA** as well.

Is this something that can be configured from within the custom post type and/or taxonomy configuration or will it need modification of the loop? What exactly would I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_list_categories` with the taxonomy argument, it is built to create hierarchal category lists but it will also support using a custom taxonomy.

### Example:

[Display hierarchal categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy)

using this you can see their hierarchal structure.

let me know the result

Comment: Not sure if this will solve my problem. I'm looking at something like hooking into the loop of the custom taxonomy archive pages and adding/filtering posts into it.

Comment: okay let me know you are trying to do in taxonomy page or any else and also it is possible by doing hooking and filter

Comment: It will be a taxonomy page.For eg., `example.com/usa` `or example.com/usa/california`. By default, these pages only show the posts contained within that particular category as well as it's children. I want to effectively reverse it, so i see the posts in the parent categories too.